# Why is my integer going up by 2 instead of 1?

Tags: java, loops, integer, bluej

I am doing a Tower of Hanoi assignment for homework. I am trying to increase the i variable by one each time but it is increasing by 2. Also, the ("[g]et, [p]ut... string is being printed twice, not once. What is happening?! Please help!>

I am tried adding a i--; on if (p) but that didn't work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Simulates a tower that can hold disks.
 * @author S. Camilleri
 * @author <your name>
 */
public class TowersOfHanoi {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // This array holds the disks. A 0 represents no disk.
        int[] tower = new int[5];

        // This index represents the first available empty spot for a disk.
        int index = 0;

        int towerCounter = 0;
        int length = tower.length;

        boolean playing = true;    
        while (playing)
        {
            /********************
             * Display the tower
             ********************/
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("{ ");

            while (towerCounter < length) {
                tower[towerCounter] = 0;
                System.out.print(tower[towerCounter]);
                towerCounter = towerCounter + 1;
            }
            String choice;
            int size;
            for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {

                /********************
                 * Get action from user
                 ********************/      
                System.out.println();      
                System.out.println("[g]et, [p]ut or [e]xit?");
                choice = input.nextLine();

                // Get
                if (choice.equals("g"))
                {
                    tower[i] = 0;

                    System.out.println();

                    towerCounter = 0;
                    i--;
                    System.out.print("{ ");

                    while (towerCounter < length) {

                        System.out.print(tower[towerCounter]);
                        towerCounter = towerCounter + 1;
                    }

                }

                // Put
                else if (choice.equals("p"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Disk?");
                    size = input.nextInt();
                    tower[i] = size;
                    towerCounter = 0;


                    System.out.print("{ ");
                    while (towerCounter < length) {

                        System.out.print(tower[towerCounter]);
                        towerCounter = towerCounter + 1;
                    }
                }

                // Exit
                else if (choice.equals("e"))
                {
                    playing = false; 
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I posted the whole code, as a request of an answerer.

Comment: Why are you doing `i--`?

Comment: What is `i` supposed to count?  Why only keep asking the user for inputs until `i` has counted up to `length`?

Comment: I think you may need to show us what calls this, if anything.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I did i-- in attempt to make the string not repeat itself.

Comment: @KevinAnderson i is counting the number of disks on the tower. It will stop when the tower fills up.

Comment: @JeremyKahan i edited the question to show the whole code.

Comment: Thanks. I see that was not it. This was subtle. I'm glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

("[g]et, [p]ut... string is being printed twice because, after you give input and hit enter, the for loop is running once for the input you gave and the one more time for the "enter" button press after the input

According to what you wanted, decrement i in  else if (choice.equals("p")) this elsed if block also

```
 else if (choice.equals("p")){
//your code
i--;
}
```

Comment: I didn't work. It still showed up twice. else if (choice.equals("p"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Disk?");
                    size = input.nextInt();
                    tower[i] = size;
                    towerCounter = 0;
                    

                    System.out.print("{ ");
                    i--;
                    while (towerCounter < length) {

                        System.out.print(tower[towerCounter]);
                        towerCounter = towerCounter + 1;
                    }
                }

Comment: replace this line 
                choice = input.nextLine(); with 
                choice = input.next(); anre remove i-- in choice.equals("p")

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ***Recursion***, the "formula" is much easier:
Here is the code:

```
public class TowerOf_Hanoi {
public static void main(String [] args){
    java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Number of Disks:   ");
    int numDisk=input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Moves are: ");
    steps(numDisk,'A','B','C');

}

public static void steps(int n, char fromTower, char toTower, char auxTower){

    //base case for Recursion
    if(n==1)        //if n=1 it will stop
        System.out.println("Move disk "+n+" from "+fromTower+" to "+toTower);
    else{
        steps(n-1,fromTower,auxTower,toTower);      //recursion
        System.out.println("Move disk "+n+" from "+fromTower+" to "+toTower);
        steps(n-1,auxTower,toTower,fromTower);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is actually an amazing idea but our teacher wants the format like this.

Comment: if (choice.equals("g"))
      {
        // TODO: take a disk from the tower
      }
      
      // Put
      else if (choice.equals("p"))
      {
        // TODO: put a disk on the tower
      }
      
      // Exit
      else if (choice.equals("e"))
      {
        playing = false; 
      }

Comment: The TODOs are supposed to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Sure, I changed the question and added the whole code.